# updation of UI with wrong values in listview

Tags: android, listview

Please excuse my English. I have an activity consists of two fragments with viewpager. And every fragment has a listview.

I am using this data in many locations, so i have created this as static.

```
class DataHandler {

         static ArrayList<MenuHolder> listOfItemsFromJson = new ArrayList<MenuHolder>();


        public static ArrayList<MenuHolder> getListOfItemsFromJson() {
            return listOfItemsFromJson;
        }


        public static void addData(MenuHolder holder) {
            listOfItemsFromJson.add(holder);

        }

        public static MenuHolder getData(int position) {

            return listOfItemsFromJson.get(position);

        }


        public static void modifyData(MenuHolder holder, int position) {

                 listOfItemsFromJson.set(position, holder);
         }
        public static int size() {

            return listOfItemsFromJson.size();
        }
    }
```

Here, My fragment code. In onCreateView(), I am clearing the previous data & 
adding the fresh data.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_combo, container, false);

        mlistView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.mListView);

//here I am clearing the previous data and loading new data 

   for (int i = 0; i < DataHandler.size(); i++) {

            if (DataHandler.getData(i).isCombo()) {
                DataHandler.removeData(i);
            }

        }


        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            MenuHolder mMenuHolder = new MenuHolder();

            mMenuHolder.setItemname(itemNames[i]);
            mMenuHolder.setImageName("@mipmap/ic_launcher");
            mMenuHolder.setItemCount("0");
            mMenuHolder.setItemprice("500");
            mMenuHolder.setUserSeleted(false);
            mMenuHolder.setCombo(true);

            DataHandler.addData(mMenuHolder);

        }
        index.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < DataHandler.size(); i++) {
            if (DataHandler.getListOfItemsFromJson().get(i).isCombo()) {
                index.add(i);
            }
        }

        mCombosAdapter = new ComboMenuAdapter(getActivity(), index);

        mlistView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mlistView.setAdapter(mCombosAdapter);


        return view;
    }
```

Here I am getting the wrong values. DataHandler.size() is wrong.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DataHandler.size(); i++) {
                if (DataHandler.getListOfItemsFromJson().get(i).isCombo()) {
                    index.add(i);
                }
             }
```

Here, I am navigating to another activity and having some modifications in dataHandler class & after coming back the list size is wrong & list size is increasing.

Comment: clear listarray after navigating new activity

Comment: I really dont think static variables should be used at all here. Especially since you have JSON strings, which are serializable and can easily be passed directly between Activities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `DataHandler` should as a singleton;

```
class DataHandler {
    private static DataHandler mInstance = null;
    ArrayList<MenuHolder> listOfItemsFromJson;

    public DataHandler getInstance() {
        if(null == mInstance) {
           mInstance = new DataHandler();
       }
    }
    public DataHandler() {
          listOfItemsFromJson = new ArrayList<MenuHolder>();
    }

    public ArrayList<MenuHolder> getListOfItemsFromJson() {
        return listOfItemsFromJson;
    }


    public void addData(MenuHolder holder) {
        listOfItemsFromJson.add(holder);

    }

    public MenuHolder getData(int position) {

        return listOfItemsFromJson.get(position);

    }


    public void modifyData(MenuHolder holder, int position) {

             listOfItemsFromJson.set(position, holder);
     }
    public int size() {

        return listOfItemsFromJson.size();
    }
}
```

You can user it like : `DataHandler.getInstance().size();`

But i think you set dataHandler as static is ugly...
you can create a adapter replace DataHandler, then your all listview can use this adapter.